# Regex to find currency without ending in a string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to identify all currency figures in a string that may or may not contain decimal places and I don't want to match any currencies that have a particular string after the last digit.

Heres my current regex: `/([\$])([0-9,]*[0-9][\.][0-9][0-9])(?!\<sup)/gi`

I've tried putting in `?` symbols to make the decimals optional but that breaks the negative lookahead

I've tried: `/([\$])([0-9,]*[0-9][\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?)(?!\<sup)/gi`

Testing this expression on https://regexr.com/ with this string:

```
$712.95 shipping, $14.95 FREE on orders $99.95 over $100 International shipping from $9.95, FREE on orders over $120 - test: $678.45<sup
```

Both the `$100` & `$120` values do not match.

---

These should match:

```
$712.95
$14.95
$99.95
$100
$9.95
$120
```

Should not match:

```
$678.45<sup
```

Comment: Can you specify the test string properly? Because with the string "$712.95 shipping, $14.95 FREE on orders $99.95 over $100 International shipping from $9.95, FREE on orders over $120 - test: $678.45", I am able to match all currencies including 100, 120 and 678.45 with regex `/([\$])([0-9,]*[0-9][\.]?[0-9]{0,2})(?!\<sup)/gi`. I am not sure why 678.45 is not supposed to match!. Please edit the question properly.

Comment: I think he doesn't want "$678.45" to match because is the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, Lakshmi. with your regex ````([\$])([0-9,]*[0-9][\.]?[0-9]{0,2})(?!\<sup)``` it matches the first $678.4 part of $678.45<sup

I need it to ignore any currency value that has "<sup" straight after the end of the currency value. 

$712.95
$14.95
$99.95
$100
$9.95
$120

Should not match: $678.45<sup

Comment: Ok. There is no '<sup' after 678.45 in the test string so I missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The negative lookahead will assert what is directly on the right is not `<sup` and it can backtrack until there will be a match.

One option is to use the negative lookahead and put it after the dollar sign to assert what comes after the dollar sign does not contain the digit format followed by  a `<sup` part:

```
\$(?!\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?<sup)\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q6nESL/2)

If you only want to match 2 digits you can use `\d{2}` instead of `\d+`

Comment: Thats heaps better, except its breaking with currency with commas. like: 1,712.77

Comment: Great work, I just need the currency to be in captured groups so I can access the numbers in my javascript. Trying to work that out now.

Comment: You can add a capturing group around the numbers. See https://regex101.com/r/Q6nESL/3

Comment: your 31925 reputation score is well deserved, thankyou so much for your help. - regex101 is also a great tool